# Processmaker4 simple screen total calculation

Tags: processmaker

Process maker 4 – first time using this.
So I have a main screen and a nested screen with the values I want to calculate

[image]

I've tried calcs with the variable and the corresponding property no luck then I move on to default value for the control input called "form_input_2"

```
var N1 = this.FA00_detallea_cant_ADT;
var N2 = this.FA00_detallea_precioag_ADT;
var total = N1 * N2;
return total;
```

how to call and convert (maybe) the correct values so this simple thing can work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close to the solution.
I have created a simple screen with three Line Inputs: Value1, Value2 and Total with variable names - input1, input2 and inputTotal.
[image: Three Line Inputs with Variable names:]

For Total Input:
In Default Value, I have used Javascript with following code:

```
return this.input1 * this.input2
```

I didn't use variables to store the values entered by the users and instead I just returned the value.
This is the final output:
[image: Output SS]

I hope this helps. Thank!